# Kubernetes behind proxy misses CSRF token

Tags: apache, nginx, kubernetes, proxy, nginx-ingress

I have a problem. On my local laptop I can build my docker image and run it. A Ruby-On-Rails application is then running on localhost:3000. Going to that page gives me a login screen and I can successfully login. Now when I publish this code to my docker repository and run it in a kubernetes cluster, I get the following error:
[image]

With status code:

```
Status Code: 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

After some googling and debugging, I read some stuff about having the correct headers in Nginx-Ingress and Apache to handle the CSRF requests. Using this I tried many ways of allowing headers and manually adding RequestHeaders, but all resulted in the same error.

In both pages I can see in the network tab the cookie in the page. The cookie in local environment contains:

```
csrftoken=7tzlvuigfaUatDBMTEJUBE53OREXHxOJ1ZzJ8h4cuHvnvUza0xLH2lglIFZ1gS4S; __profilin=p=t; _app_session=BBr2bnKi6qYJwW4yvQUU0J3Q2K8JW2i9DZ5zJS0qQmCc48uRNbPrThJhbzhnGXrxLDwD/Y8ZAW5w/x2VhXeotq3TWjWcjVucUzNPA6u6ePMcN8O7XVfcIwV2HR/aGpJ1oxB1B/TbsAcfB4LaSqckVWMZ70anWDOD+xFz0xkKPiOkd++NwnMuWix2TyaicqXmQ+JsK1yWacS2dnTWvC70xyX38JjuC/VUqu2hUFIQHeNuK7Gfp7lMCh0MEJeob43lFhgFZLOJXTC+rPYIUxMTN3aIwD0=--LsM3EqEzNEglvj6H--RHcx/5CRIYG/CWJMUER1eQ==
```

In my production environment, I can see that the entire csrftoken part is missing:

```
__profilin=p=t; _app_session=FWpoSIJ8zzB8nkRsF2A30f552HjyAVlwbMva/HN4vnKaTECnPWzfWoc/+P9k/xO+fpmd2j9ntxLFOnflB5vttwxpLL1RtjZWcPmpCWfdR0nqG3EOLPLK9yR0xrvmfKMbFsYeJ2F/hZrJIs+4iOO92CioXo1s51sZX5E3R6c9XIKn5NjHUKWKuEArVV/4MibTg/CSqPWyH3lg1bjxKoZvixSZUBdtxTq1sW5NKsJnnwPgC0ZSkQzsSquCwcxKEf9L1wPxgZQTLGRREY7JeD/+mUc0WL4=--n+JNO4hoF17EGI5K--vY2DcanQEF7ICpZwDxq9tg==
```

Why is the CSRF token not comming through in a production environment? I already tried setting RAILS_ENV to development in the production environment, so it uses a different config, but that also gives the `Status Code: 422 Unprocessable Entity`

### **IMPORTANT**

All trafic goes to my portal proxy server, which runs Apache2 and handles the SSL certificates for my domain. Apache forwards the traffic in my internal network using HTTP. Nginx-Ingress-Controller only handles http traffic because of this setup. I am not really sure if Nginx is the problem then, or Apache2?

How can I fix this CSRF issue ASAP?

### **UPDATE**

I looked into the rails logs and found the following which might cause the problem:

```
I, [2022-12-12T08:16:40.202890 #1]  INFO -- : [f785b7f7f797c67c0ab0f008e8a0eb83] Started POST "/login" for 192.168.1.10 at 2022-12-12 08:16:40 +0000                                                    
I, [2022-12-12T08:16:40.204343 #1]  INFO -- : [f785b7f7f797c67c0ab0f008e8a0eb83] Processing by AuthController#login as HTML                                                                             
I, [2022-12-12T08:16:40.204460 #1]  INFO -- : [f785b7f7f797c67c0ab0f008e8a0eb83]   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "login"=>{"email"=>"myemail@gmail.com", "password"=>"[F
W, [2022-12-12T08:16:40.204795 #1]  WARN -- : [f785b7f7f797c67c0ab0f008e8a0eb83] HTTP Origin header (https://my.site.com) didn't match request.base_url (http://my.site.com)                  
I, [2022-12-12T08:16:40.205536 #1]  INFO -- : [f785b7f7f797c67c0ab0f008e8a0eb83] Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 192)                                     
F, [2022-12-12T08:16:40.207591 #1] FATAL -- : [f785b7f7f797c67c0ab0f008e8a0eb83]
```

In my Ingress resource I now have the following:

```
annotations:
    nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: 3600s
    nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: 3600s
    nginx.org/proxy-send-timeout: 3600s
    nginx.org/proxy-pass-headers: "Set-Cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "8g"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "Host              $http_host";
      more_set_headers "X-Real-IP         $remote_addr";
      more_set_headers "X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme";
      more_set_headers "X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for";
```

And my apache conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName my.site.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.8/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.8

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =my.site.com
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

        <VirtualHost *:443>

                ServerName my.site.com

                ProxyRequests Off
                <Proxy *>
                  Order deny,allow
                  Allow from all
                </Proxy>

                SSLProxyEngine On
                SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
                SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on

                ProxyPreserveHost on
                ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.8/
                ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.8

                Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

                ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/sites/my.site.com/error.log
                CustomLog /var/log/apache2/sites/my.site.com/access.log combined

                SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.site.com/fullchain.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.site.com/privkey.pem
        </VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

I already tried adding to my Apache conf:

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
```

but that doesn't change anything...
Can someone tell me what I should change here to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I would propose adding the `origin` header in nginx. You probably also have to set it in your apache configuration to the external URL.

```
annotations:
    nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: 3600s
    nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: 3600s
    nginx.org/proxy-send-timeout: 3600s
    nginx.org/proxy-pass-headers: "Set-Cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "8g"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |

      more_set_headers "Host              $http_host";
      more_set_headers "X-Real-IP         $remote_addr";
      more_set_headers "X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme";
      more_set_headers "X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for";
      more_set_headers "origin            $remote_addr";
```

Comment: I got it working by setting: `RequestHeader set Origin "http://my.site.com"` in apache, and all the annotations you mentioned above. Is this the correct way of doing that?

Comment: Better change your apache config to `Header echo Origin` to use the origin header from the nginx request and thereby avoiding to hardcode it.

Comment: But the original is `https://` and I need to rewrite it to `http://`

Comment: You don't want to rewrite it but you want to tell that the correct URL for the CSRF token is actually `https://`. That is what the `origin` Header is for.

Comment: Adding your: `Header echo Origin` to my apache config and disabling my line gives me the same error again...?